# wifi game controller

Tags: gpio

Anyone have an idea how to use a wifi game controller to switch the GUIO on and off please.

I Have a project that uses motors to move a buggy. Would be FAB to do this with a WIFI controller or wireless keyboard, but not sure how to access the input and get this into the Python program as a button push

Comment: Do you mean the Wiimote controller for the Wii, or a wifi game controller? The Wiimote runs on bluetooth, so you will need to install the following to get python modules. sudo apt-get install python-cwiid You can find detail in Brian Hensley's Wiimote article](http://www.brianhensley.net/2013/06/raspberry-wi-fi-pi.html#more).

Comment: Good idea didnt think of the bluetooth option. As I will need a dongle any suggestions please?